# Is PostSharp suitable for authorization tasks?

Tags: attributes, wcf-security, postsharp

I need to do authorization and auditing on some WCF service methods. I'd like to do the processing in an attribute to avoid polluting my code. I've created a custom attribute using PostSharp and am wondering if this is a suitable approach or if there are any gotchas with relying on PostSharp for authorization mechanisms given that it is tweaking the MSIL?

In my WCF service class I'm using the attribute in the manner below.

```
 [AuthoriseAndAudit(UserRoleTypesEnum.Operator)]
 public JSONResult<bool> IsAliveAuthorised()
 {
     return new JSONResult<bool>() { Success = true, Result = true };
 }
```

The abbreviated attribute code is as below.

```
using PostSharp.Aspects;

[Serializable]
public class AuthoriseAndAuditAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    private static ILog logger = AppState.logger;

    private UserRoleTypesEnum _requiredRole = UserRoleTypesEnum.None;

    public AuthoriseAndAuditAttribute(UserRoleTypesEnum role = UserRoleTypesEnum.None)
    {
        _requiredRole = role;
    }

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        logger.Debug(String.Format("AuthoriseAndAuditAttribute checking {0}.", args.Method.Name));

        // Get the user's session from cookie.
        UserSession userSession = GetUserSession();

        // Check that user is in the required role.
        bool isAuthorised = (_requiredRole == UserRoleTypesEnum.None || (userSession != null && userSession.Roles.Contains(_requiredRole)));

        // Write an audit table entry.
        logger.Debug("Writing audit table entry.");

        if (!isAuthorised)
        {
            logger.Warn("Not authorised for " + args.Method.Name + ".");
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally I would say yes, but WCF has ways to do authorization so using PostSharp would be redundant and unnecessary work.

If you need to implement a custom authorization setup then yes, PostSharp will greatly aid in that.

Comment: Yes WCF has some built in authorisation mechanisms but they revolve around SOAP and/or Windows. In this case I'm exposing a REST endpoint and a small re-work of my ASP.Net membership provider does the job. What I'm attempting to do with PostSharp is make the use of my custom authentication scheme cleaner.

Comment: In that case, yes. PostSharp will let you clean up and implement your authorization/authentication schema with ease. If you need to learn PostSharp quickly, see http://programmersunlimited.wordpress.com/postsharp-principals/